# How to juxtapose and wrap texts by a step of two columns in html?

Tags: html, css

Say I have two paragraphs of texts, A and B. I want to **juxtapose them column-wise**. But the texts are long, so ideally **automatic text wrap** is involved. What I want to achieve is

> **"Text A"   "Text B"  "Continuation of Text A"  "Continuation of Text B"  ...**
> [image]

I'm only able to display Text B after Text A

```css
.vert{
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}

.mnc{
  -ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  -moz-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  -ms-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}
```

```html
<div class="vert">
  <div class="vert mnc">ᠰᡠᠸᡝᠮᠪᡝ ᡨᠠᠴᡳᡵᡝ ᡩᡝ ᠠᠮᡠᡵᠠᠨ ᠠᡴᡡ ᠰᡝᠴᡳ᠈ ᠰᡠᠸᡝ ᡤᡝᠯᡳ ᡳᠨᡝᠩᡤᡳᡩᠠᡵᡳ ᡨᠠᠴᡳᠮᡝ ᠪᡳ᠉</div>
  <div class="vert">Suwembe tacire de amuran akv seci, suwe geli inenggidari tacime bi.</div>
</div>
```

but have no clue how to achieve what I want. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Sorry, I am not quite sure what you want to do. Could you draw and attach an image to your post?

Comment: @Miu Thanks for pointing it out. I've added a picture.